# Бесплатная программа для нарезки psd шаблонов

Tags: графика

Использовал Gimp, но уже два раза столкнулся с тем, что в нем бывают проблемы с отображением psd-файлов, они отличаются от того, что можно увидеть в фотошопе. Посоветуйте программу альтернативу фотошопу, которая бы позволяла просто резать шаблон (объединять слои, вырезать, сохранять для веб, определять цвет, определять шрифт и размер букв), лишние функции не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то из требуемого сможет выполнить [плагин](http://psdplugin.codeplex.com/) для Paint.NET, который добавляет в редактор возможность работы с PSD-файлами. На странице совместимости описано, что он не сможет.

Comment: спасибо за ответ не знал о таком плагине, правда файлы он отбражает точно также как и gimp, может в gimp есть какие-то настройки, которые позволяют ему отображать файлы как в фотошопе?